# How to access JTA transactions programmatically?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jta

The only interface to the **JTA** I have seen so far is the `@TransactionAttribute`annotation. I have found nothing usable in the Oracle Java EE tutorials or using search engines...

I would like to interact with the transactions provided by the container - check programmatically if there is a current transaction - and if it is a nested transaction.

Is this at all possible?

Thank you.

EDIT: to clarify once more - I am interested in container-managed JTA transactions, not User/Bean-controlled transactions. I am not looking to create transactions, just view/control the container-generated ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JTA is an API - it does not provide implementation. For specific information you should address documentation concerning used implementation, for example http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html for Spring management or https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToUseJBossJTAStandaloneTransactionManager for Hibernate (JBoss)